# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_REST_Meta_Fields' not found in

Tags: fatal-error

I´m pretty new to PHP and cannot solve this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_REST_Meta_Fields' not found in /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/fields/class-wp-rest-comment-meta-fields.php:17 Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-settings.php(252): require()  #1 /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
 #2 /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
 #3 /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
 #4 /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/index.php(17): require('/var/www/vhosts...')
 #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/thinkotel.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/fields/class-wp-rest-comment-meta-fields.php on line 17
```

Just moved the web of hosting and remove all related to WP plugin Worfence to get this...

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified WP core files? Have you confirmed all files have been copied across, fully, and are all intact?

Comment: Thanks Tom, just replaced wp-includes and running. Cheers!